# UIPickerView didSelectRow not called if quickly tapped while scrolling beyond element 0 or final element

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview

When you scroll a `UIPickerView` component, and then watch it continue scrolling, it will eventually stop on an element and call `didSelectRow`.  This is the intended behavior.

Let's say you're on element 1 of the picker view.  If you scroll to element 0 (by dragging the component downwards)...and go past it (dragging the 0 element far down the picker view beyond the blue selection box)...when you let go, the picker view will scroll back to element 0 in order to center it back in the blue selection box, and then call `didSelectRow`.

However, if we take the same example...(ie you're on element 1 of the picker view, and scroll far beyond element 0)...if the picker view is in the middle of scrolling back to element 0, and you quickly click element 0 or the white space above it, then the picker view will awkwardly "jump" from wherever it is in the scroll animation straight to element 0, and then *won't* call `didSelectRow`.

This is a big issue, as we are now on element 0 without actually calling `didSelectRow`...thus, we have no indication that we are no longer on element 1.  Furthermore, this also happens if you scroll beyond the final element and quickly tap the final element or the white space below it, before the scroll animation is finished.  (It works normally if you try this in the middle elements for some reason)

So the question overall is, how can I detect this awkward "jump" that's more or less a glitch in the `UIPickerView`?

---

Thinking thus far:
We may have to manually handle clicks on the `UIPickerView`; though, this seems like  overkill since it's only broken on the first and final elements of the pickerview...

---

Another Update:
After trying a few standard apple apps (say Clock app) on the iPhone, I realized that this problem actually occurs in those apps as well (select am on the clock app, scroll past pm, then click "save" before it finishes scrolling back to pm).  You'll end up having am still selected.  So it seems it's an apple problem, and quite possibly can't be fixed.